# PHP configuration overriding the .htaccess caching headers

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, caching, mod-expires

I have been trying setting up caching for my site's static files like jpg, png, css etc. but getting no success so far, I figured out that PHP's configuration is taking over the .htaccess is config.

I have verified that mod_expires.so is uncommented in my httpd.conf.

I tried following in .htaccess but in vain.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
<FilesMatch "\.(jpe?g|png|gif|js|css|ttf|eto|svg|woff|otf)$">
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

even tried without success

```
<FilesMatch "\.(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</FilesMatch>
```

I then found that my php.ini has `session.cache_limiter = nocache` I changed it to `session.cache_limiter = public` and my `session.cache_expire=180`
after changing this config in php.ini and restarting apache, I found that response header for images changed as below

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 19 Sep 2014 07:33:58 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.10
Expires: Fri, 19 Sep 2014 10:33:58 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=10800
Last-Modified: Mon, 05 Dec 2011 19:08:22 GMT
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

What I want to do is to cache the images and css/js files for "access plus 1 month"

any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ExpiresByType` directive:

```
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I have tried that as well :(

Comment: Yes, that's what I mentioned that it seems that PHP config is overriding the htaccess directives.

Comment: PHP config cannot override caching of `text/javascript` OR `image/gif`. Try commenting out your `FilesMatch` block and test in a new browser. Also do you have `ExpiresActive on` before these lines?

Comment: No luck, same result :(

Comment: Good luck with your testing since only you have all the resources/files available to debug. I can only assure that this is working code.

Comment: Thank you for responses, I just figured out that my codes are working for caching on Chrome but in FF it's the same result

Comment: Actually in FF with "Live HTTP Headers" plugin, It's showing expires like 19 Nov, 1981 08:52:00 GMT